# Change text when div has multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I trying to create a function that can change the text of back and forward arrows when a specific slide is active. I'm using fullpage.js to create the slides.

the slides are formatted like this:

```
<div class="slide start table active">slide content </div>
<div class="slide doelwitten table">slide content </div>
<div class="slide strategie table">slide content </div>
<div class="slide troepen table">slide content </div>
```

Whenever a slide is active the class active is assigned to the slide like so:

```
<div class="slide start table active">slide content </div>
```

And this is the code i was trying out to achieve that result

```
if ( $('.slide').hasClass('doelwitten') && $('.slide').hasClass('active')) {
             $('.controlArrow.prev p').text('link1')
             $('.controlArrow.next p').text('link2')
        }

if ( $('.slide').hasClass('start') && $('.slide').hasClass('active')) {
             $('.controlArrow.prev p').text('link2')
             $('.controlArrow.next p').text('link3')
        }
```

But when i test the code only the first function is executed and the texts of the links don't change when a specific slide turned active.

I'm pretty new to jquery so any advice would be appreciated. i have been searching for 3hours so i guess it's time for some help :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show the rest of the code that uses the `if` statements (as that is where the solution is needed). A JSFiddle of the problem would be even better :)

Comment: How and when are you calling this code? It needs to be called and processed everytime a slide is changed. It should be a function that can be called over n over.

Comment: The function needs to be called on every transition . Update and show complete code.

Comment: end your statements with a semicolon ;

Comment: the code is called at the bottom of the page where the rest of the scripts are called. These are the functions that make the slides move:

    $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideLeft();
    $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the plugin callbacks to do it such as the [`afterSlideLoad`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex) one.

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    afterSlideLoad: function (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {

        var currentActiveSlide = $('.section').eq(index - 1).find('.slide').eq(slideIndex);

        if (currentActiveSlide.hasClass('start')) {
            $('.controlArrow.prev p').text('link2')
            $('.controlArrow.next p').text('link3')
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: that seems to mess up the arrows, it duplicates some of the arrows and the sliding gets messed up to.

I created an account so you can see what's going on:

www.legioen.be/wp-admin
username:test
password:testing123

page:
www.legioen.be/legioen/

Comment: I can not see your page but it shouldn't mess up anything. You are not doing anything except from changing the content of the `p` element.

Comment: It seems you are initializing the plugin twice... do it only once. Add the callback inside your previous initialization. Also, the `p` element doesn't exist inside `.controlArrow` unless you create it by your own somewhere else.

Comment: yes i created it myself. i also put the callbacks inside the previous initialization but it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: I added a live demo, but, as you can see, I had to use the `afterRender` function to add the `p` element to the `.controlArrow`.

Comment: OK i managed to get it working! i made some typo's
Thank ALOT Alvaro, you saved the day!